# jQuery Validation plugin attaches only to the first form

Tags: jquery-validate

I have noticed a strange [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin behaviour, possible a bug (tested with the latest version at http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js).

Suppose I have several forms on a page.

This code leads to only first form to be validated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").validate();
});
```

But this one attaches data validator to all forms:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").each(function() {
        $(this).validate();
    });
});
```

Is it by design? Why can't I handle all forms at once?

Answer (score 0):

The [api for validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) does state that it "Validates the selected form" (not forms), but I agree that that's not very jQueryish. Maybe you should suggest it as an enhancement, I can't imagine that breaking any old code?